# is it possible to pin services, deployments in Anthos Service Mesh topology view to custom places/locations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like every time I enter topology view to see services likes this:

[image]

But instead everytime I reload it is displayed like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to pin services and deployments in the service mesh UI. It is automatically generated based on the service relationship inside the mesh.

But if you really want to pin or edit the UI, you may want to experiment on installing and connect the service mesh to [Kiali](https://kiali.io/docs/installation/) since the Anthos service mesh is base on Istio service mesh, you can refer to this [link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Anthos/Connecting-Managed-Anthos-Service-Mesh-to-Kiali/m-p/175509) for more information.